# Reading csv from pandas having both quotechar and delimiter for a column value

Tags: python, csv, pandas, data-manipulation

Here is the content of a csv file 'test.csv', i am trying to read it via pandas read_csv()

```
"col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"
"v1", "v2", "v3", "v4"
"v21", "v22", "v23", "this, "creating, what to do? " problems"
```

This is the command i am using -

```
messages = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=',', skipinitialspace=True)
```

But i am getting the following error -

```
CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 4 fields in line 3, saw 5
```

i want the content for column4 in line3 to be 'this, "creating, what to do? " problems'

How to read file when a column can have quotechar and delimiter included in it ?

Comment: The problem is that your csv appears to be malformed. Pandas will allow you to use `"` as a `quotechar`, but you have unescaped quote characters in your column. If your third row was instead `"v21", "v22", "v23", "this, \"creating, what to do? \" problems"`, you could use `\ ` as the `escapechar`, and this would work.

Comment: csv is not not something i am generating so can't control that.

Comment: one option thats working for me is using   `'",'`   as the delimiter but that will require an additional step of cleanup of columns to remove the other `"`

Answer (score 3):

pandas does not allow you to keep malformed rows and to be honest I don't really see a way of ignoring some `"` characters but not others in your example. I think your intuition of using `'", "'` as the delimiter and then doing a cleanup is the best approach.  If you're really worried about doing this in one line:

```
message = pd.read_csv('test.txt', sep='", "', names = ['col1','col2','col3','col4'], skiprows=1).apply(lambda x: x.str.strip('"'))
```

which handles stripping quotes in the column names as well and gives you:

```
>>> message
>>> 
  col1 col2 col3                                     col4
0   v1   v2   v3                                       v4
1  v21  v22  v23  this, "creating, what to do? " problems
```

Comment: @ragesz Can you clarify your question please. Do you mean "what if the column labels are not quoted?" or "what if certain columns contain values that are not quoted?"

Comment: I had [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37074914/python-pandas-read-csv-quotechar-does-not-work) problem and I was searching for a solution but I didn't find any, so finally I asked, and got an answer.